# Making early shabbos and tefillin

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tefilin, leil-shabbat

If someone accepted shabbos early (tosafot  shabbat), and remembered he didn't put on tefillin that day, may he put on Tefilin in order not to miss a day of performing that mitzva, or is he already bound by the prohibition of putting on Tefilin on Shabbos?

Comment: Probably he would not be able to put on tefillin just as he cannot do melacha or daven mincha. This is from logic only so I am leaving it as a comment.

Comment: There is a prohibition of donning Tefillin on Shabbos? Can you source this? Why should Halacha care about "miss[ing] a day of [the] mitzva"?

Comment: Ha. "Bound" by the prohibition...

Answer (score 1):

According to Achronim in the end of Siman 30 they discuss on a regular day of the week if one already Davend Ma'ariv he would still put on Tefilin, in Mishna Berurah 600:7 he mentions about a scenario of a congregation who did not blow the Shofar on Rosh Hashana until after they were Mekabel Shabbos - he says that they blow without a Beracha, accordingly one would put on Tefilin in the scenario in question.

Comment: but shofar is a mitzva chiyuvis

Comment: @DoubleAA And Tefilin is not?!

Comment: Sorta. Most people don't wear tefillin whenever they are "supposed" to. Are you suggesting putting on tefillin after early maariv every night because of the obligation??

Answer (score 1):

The Sefer Avnei Yashfei 8:54:1 writes that if one forgot to put on teffilin and was mekabel shabbas after plag and even made kiddush(actual story happened) he can put on teffilin since he accepted shabbas by mistake and would not forgo his mitzva of teffilin if he remembered. He brings a few sources for support,the Taz 600:2,The Shoel U'Mashiv 2:23 and it is also brought in the Mahrsham(Daas Torah 261:1).

He brings The Shevet Hakhasei 5:49 who holds one should put on teffilin but without the bracha,this is also mashmah from the Taz(600:2)

He also held that the bachur had to make kiddush a second time,since when he put on teffilin it shows he said it by mistake and it really was not shabbas for him yet(if one would ask about a bracha levatalh ,he talks about it later on in the tshuva)

Comment: So how does this fit with korban pesach? If someone forgot to put on tefillin and brought a korban pesach is it chag hapesach for him and he doesn’t put on tefillin or does he because he would’ve never brought it before putting on tefillin. Difference is that the korban isn’t being mekabel it early you physically changed the status of the day?‍♂️ Headache.

Comment: Meaning m’draisa it’s now chag pesach wether or not you would have brought the korban. The question is wether or not shabbos is m’draisa brought in when you are mekabel it early.