# Does one fulfill the mitzvah of tefillin if he wears it at night time?

Tags: tefilin, zemanim, evening-night

I've seen a few questions on this site confirming that the mitzvah for wearing tefillin is during the entire day. Indeed, on Tish'a B'Av tefillin is not worn in the morning for Shacharit but for Mincha.

However, while I haven't seen anyone wearing tefillin at night, if one did, would he fulfil the requirement of wearing tefillin for that day? If not, what is the source / support that tefillin can be worn only during daylight hours, and when does the permissible time end?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53321 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97155 . Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59145 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57214 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38849

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SA OC 30:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.30.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) rules that

> One is prohibited to put Tefillin on at night since he may forget
> [that he has them on] and sleep in them. But if he puts them on before
> the sun sets and it happens to get dark, even if he wears them the
> whole night, it is permitted.

The Rambam ([Hilchot Tefillin end of 4:11](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925425/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Four.htm)) rules this is a transgression *d'oraita*.

> A person who puts on tefillin after sunset transgresses a Scriptural
> prohibition, as [implied by Exodus 13:10]: "And you shall observe this
> statute... from day to day."

Since we have a rule that one does not get credit for a *mitzva ha-ba'a be-aveira* (a *mitzva* that came by the way of a transgression through the same object, see e.g., [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/talmud/seder-moed/massekhet-sukka/mitzva-ha-baa-ba-aveira)), one wouldn't fulfil the requirement of wearing tefillin for that day.

The last time for putting on tefillin ideally is before *shkia*, or before *tzeit hakochavim* but there is a debate if one can say the blessing (see OC 30:2 with commentaries, or [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/until-when-during-the-day-may-one-put-on-tefillin/#_ftn1) and [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1114)).

Comment: We all know it's not a "* transgresses a Scriptural prohibition*", he just finds an Asmachtah to distance people from this practice. If wearing Teffilin is an all-day Mitzvah I think one nevertheless is Yotzeh, less than perfect, but still. BTW, how many levels of Yotze do we have - is it binary or a scale?

Comment: @AlBerko I don't know that. I think the Rambam follows R Yohanan in [Menachot 36b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.36b.6?lang=bi)

Comment: Please provide source for: "Since we have a rule that one does not get credit for a mitzva ha-ba'a be-aveira (a mitzva that came by the way of a transgression through the same object, see e.g., here), one wouldn't fulfil the requirement of wearing tefillin for that day."

Comment: Your source is questionable because there is an idea of overriding prohibitions to fulfill a mitzvah if there is no other way.

Comment: @KennyXiong I updated the broken link re *mitva habaa be aveira*. Regarding your last comment that "there is an idea of overriding prohibitions to fulfill a mitzvah if there is no other way" this doesn't apply in case of negligence (e.g., someone not putting on tefillin during the day), see e.g., [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Aseh_Doche_Lo_Taaseh)

Comment: It's got nothing to do with Mitzvah Haba'ah be'aveira - if the Torah says it's prohibited to wear Tehillim at night then obviously there can't also be a mitzvah in wearing tefillin at night. It's a more open question if the prohibition is only Rabbinic (AFAIK it's discussed regarding blowing Shofar on Shabbos)